# my live() method goes crazy

Tags: jquery

first some code:

I have many elements like that:

```
<section class="item>
     <div class="caption">
     </div>
</section>
```

the "caption" is hidden, when you go on the "item" the "caption" came in.

I did this before with hover() and worked fine, but now I need to have it live(), because I'm adding some more "item"s with an ajax() call.

What's happening now is that when "caption" is showed, it takes precedence over item, because it is styled as absolute. Here some other code:

```
.caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    display: none;
}
```

I like this style because sometimes my "item" can have any size, and "caption" just follows it. But let's go on.

Symptoms: when I mouse-enter on my "item" the caption shows, then instantly goes away, then goes in, then goes out. Like mad. I know why, I suppose it's because my "caption" even if lives into "item" takes precedence, so "item" is no more in mouse-enter event. So "caption" leaves, and "item" fires another mouse-enter. And so on, until the end of time.

Here is my javascript, how can I say to live() to behave like it did before with hover()?

```
$('.item').live({
    mouseenter : function() {
        $(this)
        .find('.caption')
        .animate({
            opacity: 1,
            height: 'toggle'
            }, 'fast');

    },

    mouseout : function() {
        $(this)
        .find('.caption')
        .animate({
            opacity: 0,
            height: 'toggle'
        }, 'fast');     

    }

})
```

thank you!

Comment: I believe `mouseout` should be `mouseleave`

Comment: Not much help for your problem, but note that `live` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7+. If you're using 1.7+, use `on` instead. If you're not, use `delegate` instead.

Comment: Here's a quote form the jQuery documentation about .live(): As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: Ensure the typo in your <section class="item"> line (missing quote) is not replicated in your actual code - that will cause all kinds of fun.

Comment: @KevinB yeah! please add it as an answer so I can +1!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mouseout` should be `mouseleave` to correctly mimic the `$.fn.hover` method.

Comment: If anyone cares, this is because mouseout is the default javascript event, which triggers as soon as the cursor leaves the element, even if it's for a child of the same element, while mouseleave is jQuery's improved version, which doesn't count entering a child as leaving the element.

Answer (score 2):

I took the time to test this, so my answer is a bit late. Here is the use of `mouseleave` demonstrated

http://jsfiddle.net/DvReQ/

---

[Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825423/my-live-method-goes-crazy/8825660#comment11017323_8825627) explains why `mouseout` doesn't work, but `mouseleave` does:

> This is because mouseout is the default javascript event, which triggers as soon as the cursor leaves the element, even if it's for a child of the same element, while mouseleave is jQuery's improved version, which doesn't count entering a child as leaving the element